# Bigcommerce Stencil - What is Required and Help Setting Up

Tags: bigcommerce

I just got access to the new Stencil beta and I have no idea what to do. I have reviewed all of the documentation on the BC developer website, but I don't know how to proceed. I am also not sure if I will even be able to create designs in Stencil since I don't know Handlbars or json - are those programming skills required or can we still rely on CSS and HTML for most design customization? BC told me there is no support for getting set up and to ask in this forum instead.

Normally I would look under the hood of an existing theme to see how it's built and try "learning on the job" but since I can't even get access to the files, I am at a loss. I created an account on GitHub but I have never used it so I don't know where to look for the files (I did a search but there are thousands of files there and I again couldn't figure out where to start). Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can determine if using Stencil is even feasible for my projects?

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars compiles serverside as HTML. You do still have stylesheets, but we are using some SASS custom functions (documented in Stencil docs).

I'd recommend taking a look here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/getting-started-with-handlebars-js

Comment: Okay, so if I don't know javascript and don't know what SASS is, I'm guessing this isn't going to be easy for me to do? I don't intend on building themes from scratch; I just need to be able to move elements around on the page. This has been very easy with the existing BC templates between literally moving code in the template files and then applying CSS.

Comment: Currently, you can't download the purchasable themes. You only have the basic one from scratch to build on in Stencil. For more info on sass: http://sass-lang.com/ (Syntactically Awesome Style Sheets, basically CSS with a little umph). Understanding javascript will be something that is necessary to work with a javascript templating language though.